# one at a time expression evaluation

Tags: expression, symbolic-math

I'm building a SIC/XE assembler.

There's a part where I have to send an expression to the loader to evaluate it but the loader takes it in a certain format.

Example:

```
expression = a + b - c
```

assembler modification record(which loader reads):

```
M^some_address^some_number^+a
M^some_address^some_number^+b
M^some_address^some_number^-c
```

Up to here it's easy but when the expression gets complicated I can't find a way to solve complex expression like this:

```
expression = a + c * f - d * e
```

Answer (score 0):

Best advice: Find a library (written in the language you are using) that handles parsing and evaluating simple arithmetical expressions.